# Volume on my device doesn't effect the volume

Tags: ios, audio, volume

.h

```
SystemSoundID sound1;
```

.m

```
NSURL *soundURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Woosh" ofType:@"mp3"]];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL1, & sound1);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound1);
```

This is the only code i use to play my Woosh.mp3 sound. I ran the app on my iPad and when i changed the volume on the device, the volume of the sound didn't change. I was wondering if there might be another way to implement sound into the app, or add the capability to change volume to this way.

Comment: to Play audio file you can use audioplayer controller or MPMoviePlayerController so you can manage the volume also in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *soundurl   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"mysound" withExtension: @"caf"];
AVAudioPlayer *mySoundPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundurl error:&error];
mySoundPlayer .volume=1.0f; //between 0 and 1
[mySoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
mySoundPlayer.numberOfLoops=0; //or more if needed
[mySoundPlayer play];
```

Comment: thanks this method worked, but at the end of the second line you put "&error", this kept bringing up an error message on Xcode so i changed it to "nil" and it seems to work well now.

Comment: U can write nil also or you can write &error  and first you need to declare "NSError* error = nil;" .   this is for if error occurse while allocation object of AvAUdioPlayer